# Unfair 3 Sided Die Question

Tags: probability

Say you have an unfair 3-sided die.

Side 1 will be rolled with probability $P_1.$
Side 2 will be rolled with probability $P_2.$
Side 3 will be rolled with probability $P_3.$

Find a formula for the probability that the 8th 3 will be rolled on the 10th
roll.
 Here is how I started:

$$
\sum_{i=8}^{10}P(T_8 = i) $$

Im just having trouble with that expansion?

Comment: Have you considered that this is a binomial setup? Success is you rolling a 3, and failure is not rolling a three. So you need to check what is the probability of 7 successes in the first 9 rolls, and multiply this by the probability of getting a three on the tenth roll.

Answer (score 1):

Since the trials are independent, this is just the probability to get exactly 7 '3' in the first 9 rolls and a '3' on the 10th roll.

Comment: so would it be 9choice2 * P^8(1-P)^2 ?

Comment: What's the probability of 7 successes in 9 trials?

Comment: That would just use the Bernoulli formula but How does that combine with the last part...8th 3 on 10 roll?

Comment: No, because it is the sum of B. trials - Binomial. You multiply it by the probability of the success in the last trial.

Comment: Well I am very far off. How would you start writing this problem then? Im having a tough time understanding this concept.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already given seems clear enough to me, but let's try wording it a little differently:

Treat each roll of the die as a Bernoulli trial.
Rolling a '3' is a success. Any other roll is a failure.
So the trial succeeds with probability $P_3.$

Now roll the first $9$ rolls and add up the number of successes observed
in these $9$ rolls. Let $Y$ be the number of successes observed.

Then $Y$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n = 9$ and $p = P_3.$
The probability that you succeeded $7$ times in these $9$ trials is
written $P(Y = 7).$

Now roll the die a tenth time. This roll is independent of the first $9$ rolls. But that roll will be the 8th '3' if and only if both of the following two things must occur:

1. The tenth roll is a '3'.
2. $Y = 7.$

Find the probability that both events occur.

Comment: so in essence, you are using a negative binomial distribution. But how would you formulate a way to get to an answer? That is where I am struggling.

Comment: You can apply a negative binomial, but that is not the approach I meant to suggest here. $Y$ has an _ordinary_ binomial distribution. The tenth roll is just a single Bernoulli trial. You want the probability that the two specified events both occur--a very basic formula of probability.